# What is the best way to select a row based on whether or not the previous row has a matching value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know about the lag function, but I'm confused on how to make it work in my specific situation. I have four columns - `id`,`query`,`url`, and `position`, where query is a search query, url is the url found, and position is the position that the url was found in.

I'd like to query every instance of when an entry (with the same query and url) changes position from an integer to None, when ordered by id.

Example:

```
id | query | url | position
------------------------------
0 | 'dog' | 'dog.com' | 2
1 | 'cat' | 'cat.com' | None
2 | 'dog' | 'dog.com' | 3
4 | 'cat' | 'cat.com' | 5
5 | 'dog' | 'dog.com' | None
6 | 'cat' | 'cat.com' | 2
7 | 'bird' | 'bird.com' | 9
8 | 'bird' | 'bird.com' | None
```

I'd want to return:

```
5 | 'dog' | 'dog.com'
8 | 'bird' | 'bird.com'
```

(Since those are the two entries where the position changed from an integer to None)

Answer (score 0):

In the following query, `LAG(position, 1)` means that we want to obtain the previous row's `position` value and `OVER (PARTITION BY query, url ORDER BY id)` means that the "previous row" is determined by considering rows with the same `query` and `url` values and ordering by `id`.

Once the position from the previous row has been determined we can select rows with a `NULL` `position` whose predecessor's `position` was not `NULL`.

```sql
-- Create an in-memory "table" using the data from the question
WITH  tbl (id, query, url, position) AS (
    VALUES 
        (0, 'dog', 'dog.com', 2),
        (1, 'cat', 'cat.com', NULL),
        (2, 'dog', 'dog.com', 3),
        (4, 'cat', 'cat.com', 5),
        (5, 'dog', 'dog.com', NULL),
        (6, 'cat', 'cat.com', 2),
        (7, 'bird', 'bird.com', 9),
        (8, 'bird', 'bird.com', NULL)
    ),

-- Compute the "previous position" values
tbl2 AS (
    SELECT id, 
           query, 
           url,
           position, 
           LAG(position, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY query, url ORDER BY id) AS prev_position
    FROM tbl
)

-- Select the records that our criteria
SELECT id, query, url
FROM tbl2
WHERE position IS NULL
AND prev_position IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id;
```

Result

```
 id │ query │   url    
════╪═══════╪══════════
  5 │ dog   │ dog.com
  8 │ bird  │ bird.com
```